# Group by each unique id and then find number of purchases for each brand

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have customer purchase data for the last 3 years. A sample below:

```
 customer_id|date      |sales_amount|product_type
 479485     |20190120  | 500        | bags
 479485     |20180320  | 200        | clothes
 479485     |20180321  | 200        | clothes
 472848     |20191020  | 100        | clothes
```

I want to find for each unique customer id, number of transactions they had over the three years for the different product type. Ideally a value count on product type for each unique customer id. So for `customer_id` = 479485 the output :

```
 customer_id
 479485     |bags      | 1       
            |clothes   | 2
```

I have tried doing a pivot table but it is not giving me my ideal result:

`pd.pivot_table(clusters, index=['customer_id', 'product_type'], aggfunc='sum')`

bonus: If I wanted to do the same thing but look at it but separate it by year is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input data is like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'cust_id':[479485,479485,479485,472848],
                 'date':['20190120','20180320','20180321','20191020'],
                 'sales_amount':[500,200,200,100],
                 'product_type':['bags','clothes','clothes','clothes']})
```

I would do something like this:

```
df.groupby(['cust_id','product_type'])['sales_amount'].count()
```

Grouping by year is of course possible. There are several options but you have to look at the datetime library to convert the date column into a datetime object and then work on that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
temp = df.groupby(['customer_id', 'product_type'])['date'].count()

temp
customer_id  product_type
472848       clothes         1
479485       bags            1
             clothes         2
```